# Unable to write a MySQL query to work correctly

Tags: mysql

I have two tables that I am working with in this query. The first table is "users" and the second table is "logs". I am trying to display the column "username" from "users" and the column "time_stamp" from logs but I only want the results to show the most recent "time_stamp" for each "username"

Here is my query:

```
 SELECT users.username, logs.time_stamp 
 FROM users, logs 
 WHERE users.u_id=logs.user_id 
   AND logs.user_action='user login' 
 GROUP BY (username) 
 ORDER BY logs.time_stamp DESC
```

This is what I get:

```
Alex   2013-02-20 10:51:52
Bill   2013-02-13 12:32:33
Mike   2013-02-13 10:53:47
Rick   2013-02-08 12:34:50
Admin  2013-02-08 01:55:31
```

It looks OK at first glance, but it is not displaying the most recent time_stamp for each of the users. I can't figure out what I am doing wrong, any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: If you just want the most recent timestamp, why are you getting the user action? If the user login wasn't the most recent action, it won't show the most recent timestamp now, will it?

Comment: Well I have more actions in that column, not just 'user login'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use MAX aggregate function:

```
SELECT
  users.username,
  MAX(logs.time_stamp)
FROM
  users INNER JOIN logs ON users.u_id=logs.user_id
WHERE 
  logs.user_action='user login' 
GROUP BY username
```